# Unable to Decrease CIVignette effect using UISlider

Tags: ios, swift3, core-image, cifilter

I have used `CIVignette` effect for My Photo Editing app. It applying based on Slider's Changing event. I have used following code and my issue is whenever I increased slider's value Vignette effect is appeared but whenever I decrease slider's value the Vignette effect does not decrease.
Please Help.

```
@IBAction func slider(_ sender: UISlider) {

        let startImage = CIImage(image: imgEdited!)!

        let vignetteFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIVignette")!

        let radius = 5

        vignetteFilter.setValue(startImage, forKey:kCIInputImageKey)
        vignetteFilter.setValue(sender.value, forKey:"inputIntensity")
        vignetteFilter.setValue(radius, forKey:"inputRadius")

        let filteredImageData = vignetteFilter.value(forKey: kCIOutputImageKey) as! CIImage
        let filteredImageRef = self.context.createCGImage(filteredImageData, from: filteredImageData.extent)

        imgImage.image = UIImage.init(cgImage: filteredImageRef!)
        self.imgEdited = imgImage.image
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code based on my answer to the other `SO` post [Blur effect using slider Is not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46108659/blur-effect-using-slider-is-not-working-properly/46625846?noredirect=1#comment80282677_46625846).

```
 @IBAction func slider(_ sender: UISlider) {

    let startImage = CIImage(image: UIImage(named: "Your Image Name")!) // You should initialise your UIImage here not UIImageView
    let vignetteFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIVignette")! 

    vignetteFilter.setValue(startImage, forKey:kCIInputImageKey)
    vignetteFilter.setValue(sender.value, forKey:kCIInputIntensityKey)
    vignetteFilter.setValue(5, forKey:kCIInputRadiusKey)

    let filteredImageData = vignetteFilter.value(forKey: kCIOutputImageKey) as! CIImage
    let filteredImageRef = self.context.createCGImage(filteredImageData, from: filteredImageData.extent)

    self.imgView.image = UIImage.init(cgImage: filteredImageRef!) // Output

 }
```

**Output from the Sim:**

[image]

Comment: Does this perform well? Why not use a `GLKView` and a single `CIContext`? That way you use the GPU and you can take the *current* CIImage being rendered in the GLKView and output a `UIImage` when sharing/saving. I'm guessing you'll see a 5-10 fold performance increase. (Of course, in the simulator you'll see just about the same - or more - decrease. But take advantage of those GPUs when you can.)

Comment: Thanks for your comment @dfd. but, `SO` pointed out on the other related post his not using `GLKView`.

Comment: Thanks. Still - how's the performance? I've found dynamically using a slider to alter a `CIFilter` and creating a `UIImage` to be... very stuttery. And from what I'm seeing in your output example, this is the case here.

Comment: It works good on real device @dfd as you know coreImage rendering on simulator is always slackish...

Comment: @dfd Just tested on `GLKView` it seems `Memory consumption, CPU usage and Energy impact` almost identical to my posted answer on Simulator and real Device. But, Some how i noticed `GLKView` rendering smoothly upon `UISlider` scrolls.Thanks...

Comment: Thank you! I have code for that if you or the OP wishes. (Hate to think I wasted time using the GPU.)

Comment: Post your answer. Your answer not only helps OP it will help others too....